# How can I read a file into a list of tuples including the line number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read a file into a  list of tuples that stores the word itself and the line it is on.

```py
listinput = []

with open(args.infile, "r") as filein:
    for line in filein:
        line = line.strip(" .,!?\n\t")
        line = line.lower()
        tuples = line.split()
        listinput.append(tuples)
print(listinput)
```

I also don't know how to get the line number in it.
I am also not sure if i created a list of tuples right.

Comment: could you please also provide an example file, and expected + actual output for the current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the content of the file, as well as the current and expected output, is not specified so I'm not sure what the content looks like, but:

you can use `enumerate` to also get the line number as you iterate lines

does this work for you?

```py
listinput = []

with open(args.infile, "r") as filein:
    for num, line in enumerate(filein):
        line = line.strip(" .,!?\n\t")
        line = line.lower()
        tuples = (num, *line.split())
        listinput.append(tuples)
print(listinput)
```